# How to draw polyline in google maps flutter between user location and a marker?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, routes, polyline, direction

This is my first post in this site so I hope I get the help I need.

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to use flutter_polyline_points plugin to draw polylines or routes between the user location and a marker that will be specified by the user. I searched online and I went over many tutorials but I kept getting errors or it didn't work with my codes.

So can someone please help me with achieving that?

Thanks in advance!

These are my codes:

```
const LatLng dest_location = LatLng(26.0667, 50.5577);

class _NavPageScreenState extends State<NavPage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  late GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;
  late Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = {};
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

  void locatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;
    LatLng latlatposition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        new CameraPosition(target: latlatposition, zoom: 16);
    newGoogleMapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  static final CameraPosition _UserLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(26.0667, 50.5577),
    zoom: 16,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Google Maps'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            }),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: _UserLocation,
        polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
          newGoogleMapController = controller;
          _getPolyline();
          locatePosition();
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _addMarker(LatLng position, String id, BitmapDescriptor descriptor) {
    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(id);
    Marker marker =
        Marker(markerId: markerId, icon: descriptor, position: position);
    markers[markerId] = marker;
  }

  _addPolyLine(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    PolylineId id = PolylineId("poly");
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 8,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _getPolyline() async {
    /// add origin marker origin marker
    _addMarker(
      LatLng(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude),
      "origin",
      BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    );

    // Add destination marker
    _addMarker(
      LatLng(dest_location.latitude, dest_location.longitude),
      "destination",
      BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(90),
    );

    List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      "API_KEY",
      PointLatLng(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude),
      PointLatLng(dest_location.latitude, dest_location.longitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.walking,
    );
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    } else {
      print(result.errorMessage);
    }
    _addPolyLine(polylineCoordinates);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post here the error messages you are getting?

Comment: @NelsonJr. Hello Nelson, Thanks for your reply! I tried many different ways and I got different errors, so to make things easier, I edited my codes with one of your ways to draw polyline as I saw an answer of u to a similar problem, i don't have an error in my code using your approach but i cant add a marker or draw polyline. I just see the map. and what im trying to do is to let the user choose any destination by putting a marker on the map and then navigate to it, where a polyline will be drawn to the specified location/marker (destination and origin are not fixed)

Comment: Thanks for updating your code @Aziz! let me check it

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code, I was getting the below error on `_addMarker` method

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

That's because `currentPosition` is not being assigned the correct `position` which comes from the result of `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition` method

That's the reason why the polyline doesn't appear.

I fixed the code and I was able to display the polyline. Please see the code and screenshot below

```
const LatLng dest_location = LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962);

class _NavPageScreenState extends State<NavPage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;
  Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = {};
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

      
  void locatePosition() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;
  }

  static final CameraPosition _UserLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    //target: LatLng(26.0667, 50.5577),
    zoom: 16,
  );
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    locatePosition();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Google Maps'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
               Navigator.push(
                 context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
            }),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: _UserLocation,
        polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
          newGoogleMapController = controller;
          _getPolyline();

          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _addMarker(LatLng position, String id, BitmapDescriptor descriptor) {
    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(id);
    Marker marker =
        Marker(markerId: markerId, icon: descriptor, position: position);
    markers[markerId] = marker;
  }

  _addPolyLine(List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates) {
    PolylineId id = PolylineId("poly");
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: id,
      points: polylineCoordinates,
      width: 8,
    );
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _getPolyline() async {
    /// add origin marker origin marker
    _addMarker(
      LatLng(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude),
      "origin",
      BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    );

    // Add destination marker
    _addMarker(
      LatLng(dest_location.latitude, dest_location.longitude),
      "destination",
      BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(90),
    );

    List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      "Your_key",
      PointLatLng(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude),
      PointLatLng(dest_location.latitude, dest_location.longitude),
      travelMode: TravelMode.walking,
    );
    if (result.points.isNotEmpty) {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    } else {
      print(result.errorMessage);
    }
    _addPolyLine(polylineCoordinates);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @NelsonJr. it is working now and the polyline is showing, but the destination is fixed, is it possible to modify the code to make the destination marker changeable where it appears on tap? so for example the user get to select any place on the map by tapping (as a destination) and then a marker will show (the destination marker) and a polyline will be drawn to that destination?